# How to use autocompleteBounds in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, google-places-api

I want to use AutocompleteViewController in a special area with this Lat and Long

```
let SOUTHWEST_LATITUDE = 35.60;
   let SOUTHWEST_LONGITUDE = 51.11;
   let NORTHEAST_LATITUDE = 35.80;
   let NORTHEAST_LONGITUDE = 51.60;
```

and now I don't know how to use them in my code!!
here in my code

```
public func googlePlacesVC() -> UIViewController{
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
     //how to use this ?
    //autocompleteController.autocompleteBounds????
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    return autocompleteController
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define a `GMSCoordinateBounds` with the **southWest** coordinate and the **northEast** coordinate, also you need to fix your constants declarations, statics constants are final already, also the type of the constant must be after the constant name, not before

**UPDATE**
Another thing you need to use         `autocompleteController.autocompleteBoundsMode = .restrict` if you want to restrict the results only to this bounds

**Full Code**

```
private static let SOUTHWEST_LATITUDE : Double = 35.60;
private static let SOUTHWEST_LONGITUDE : Double  = 51.11;
private static let NORTHEAST_LATITUDE : Double  = 35.80;
private static let NORTHEAST_LONGITUDE : Double = 51.60;


public func googlePlacesVC() -> UIViewController{
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    let northEastCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ViewController.NORTHEAST_LATITUDE, longitude: ViewController.NORTHEAST_LONGITUDE)
    let southWestCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ViewController.SOUTHWEST_LATITUDE, longitude: ViewController.SOUTHWEST_LONGITUDE)
    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: southWestCoordinate, coordinate: northEastCoordinate)
    //how to use this ?
    autocompleteController.autocompleteBounds = bounds
    autocompleteController.autocompleteBoundsMode = .restrict
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    return autocompleteController
}
```

this works, was tested ;)

Comment: Thanks, man you saved my time :)
but I got this error when I want to use restrict

<<value of type 'GMSAutocompleteViewController' has no member 'autocompleteBoundsMode'>>

Comment: Did you import `GooglePlaces` ?

Comment: yes I did that  import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

Comment: But that member is in the AutoCompleteViewController, check here https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_view_controller?hl=es-419 @Mohsenmokhtari

Comment: can you update your question adding your current updated code? @Mohsenmokhtari

Comment: @Mohsenmokhtari is working properly now?, you are missing only this line `autocompleteController.autocompleteBoundsMode = .restrict`